# What is the difference if I set a reversed list to recyclerView Adapter rather than calling setReverseLayout(true) and setStackFromEnd(true)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I want to reverse the RecyclerView. One way to do this is:

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
// Set the layout manager to your recyclerView
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

What is the difference if I set a reversed list to RecyclerView Adapter rather than calling `setReverseLayout(true)` and `setStackFromEnd(true)` on LayoutManager?

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)

Comment: `setReverseLayout(true)` = **position 0** is the *first element of the not-reversed list* , reversed List = **position 0** *last element of the not-reversed List* nothing else !!